# Java, Read empty line

Tags: java

How can I read the empty line 
This code doesn't add the empty line, 
I tried this code

```
BufferedReader r2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Flags.txt"));
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while ((r2.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(r2.readLine());
         sb.append("\r\n");
  }

      String str = sb.toString();
      System.out.println(str);
```

outputs

```
    Dubai
    Qatar
    UAE
    United States
```

It should be like this

```
    Dubai
    Qatar
    UAE

    United States
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `readLine()` twice. Do it as follows:

```
String line = "";
while ((line = r2.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line);
     //...
}
```